# Typing: Restrict to a list of strings

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-typing

This is Python 3.7

I have a dataclass like this:

```
@dataclass
class Action:
   action: str
```

But action is actually restricted to the values "bla" and "foo". Is there a sensible way to express this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an [`Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Enum):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum

class ActionType(Enum):
    BLA = 'bla'
    FOO = 'foo'

@dataclass
class Action:
    action: ActionType

>>> a = Action(action=ActionType.FOO)
>>> a.action.name
'FOO'
>>> a.action.value
'foo'
```

Answer (score 11):

Use [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Literal) like:

```py
@dataclass
class Action:
   action: Literal["bla", "foo"]
```

The catch is that it's new in Python 3.8. If you want `Literal` in earlier Python versions you need to install [`typing-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) module. So, complete solution for Python 3.7 looks like that:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing_extensions import Literal

@dataclass
class Action:
   action: Literal["bla", "foo"]
```

Comment: Thx, unfurtunately my client is stuck on 3.7 for the next few months

Comment: you can install [typing-extension](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) in 3.7 from pip. It's the official backport of features like `Literal` to earlier versions.

Comment: @Arne, great finding. I'll add it to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just adding an example for limiting, accepted strings in a function

```
from typing import Literal

def get_time_measurement(message, unit: Literal['nanosec', 'microsec', 'millisec']):
```